# Как для сборки apserver 2.5.9 добавить мод кэш?

Tags: apache, сборка

Нашел модуль, скачал, а как что делать, не знаю. Нашел инструкцию, но то, что там сказано делать, у меня такого нет. Кто-то подскажет хорошую быструю сборку. Или все же придется самому все соединять? Если можно, то подробно.

Answer (score 1):

сборка?? чем вам денвер не нравиться? а вообще, если делать, делать ручками связку php+apache+mysql ну можно перл, еще что надо.. это уже под необходимости...